# Boxtimes and otimes have different thickness

Tags: symbols, amssymb

The amssymb package provides the symbols `\otimes` and `\boxtimes`. However, the `\boxtimes` symbol is way thicker than the `\otimes` symbol. This looks odd if both symbols appear close to each other. Is there a better way to import these symbols?

The minimal working example is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\otimes\boxtimes$
\end{document}
```

[image: times and boxtimes symbols]

Comment: Maybe you would prefer a different symbol font? How about MnSymbol or fdsymbol ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use this font, you can create your own symbol using `tikz` and then use `scalerel` to match the size of `\otimes`. This will adjust if used in script style.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, scalerel, tikz}

\renewcommand{\boxtimes}{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\tikz{\draw[line width=1.1pt](0,0)rectangle(1,1)--(0,0)(1,0)--(0,1);}}{\otimes}}}

\begin{document}
$\otimes\boxtimes$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution myself: The stmaryrd package extends the ams packages and provides the command `\varotimes`. It has the desired properties:[image: stmaryrd varotimes]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,stmaryrd}
\begin{document}
$\boxtimes \varotimes$
\end{document}
```